# I used graph.facebook for add post but when add hashtag don't work

Tags: javascript, node.js

I used graph.facebook for add post but when add hashtag with message don't work for for example code

```
curl -i -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/{page-post-id}
  ?message= when add #hashtag don't work.
  &access_token={page-access-token}"
```

Comment: You must percent-encode the hashtag in a URL: `https://graph.facebook.com/{page-post-id}?message= when add %23hashtag don't work.&access_token={page-access-token}`

Comment: it work but when add emoji it don't work

Comment: You must also encode the emoji, for example `encodeURIComponent("") = "%F0%9F%98%8A"`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.